# ORDER BY Desc (getting Asc order)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table T where im trying to order them by desc order 
I used

```
select * from T
Order by column_name desc  .
```

But im getting an Asc order instead of desc . Im unable to upload image as im new here , so pasted my results below .Please have a look at it and thanks in advance

```
970.000000

970.000000

825.000000

1205.000000

1170.000000

1170.000000

1050.000000

1000.000000

1000.000000

1000.000000
```

Comment: convert your string column into a number

Comment: Column data type char perhaps?

Comment: what happens if you order by asc?

Comment: Getting this order 1000.000000
1000.000000
1000.000000
1050.000000
1170.000000
1170.000000
1205.000000
825.000000
970.000000
970.000000

Comment: You are getting this order because the "numbers" are sorting as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the column to numeric when ordering:

```
SELECT *
FROM T
ORDER BY CAST(column_name AS NUMERIC(12,6)) DESC
```

I would recommend storing your numeric data in a numeric type column for the very reason that it will be difficult to work with such data in your database when it is being stored as text.

Comment: Thanks a lot for recommending this . This actually solved my problem .

Answer (score 0):

Are these column names? The query written by you will give rows from the table in descending order of column names

Comment: These are the results im getting while executing the query in desc order.  casting the column to numeric solved this problem . Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

You are storing numeric data as text.  That can cause problems like this.  Tim's answer is one approach.

Another will work on your data because all have the same format:

```
order by len(col) desc,
         col desc
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But converting it to numeric solved my issue